# Google Speech To Text API: Extracting audio from mp4

Tags: python, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I am trying to extract text from video (mp4) file saved in AWS S3 using Python. I am able to make it working using audio file, but not with an MP4. Is it possible to use MP4 directly or should I extract the audio using ffmpeg or something similar.

I am referring to the following link: [Google Video Transcribing](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/video-model#speech-select-model-python)

```
def transcribe_model_selection(speech_file, model):
"""Transcribe the given audio file synchronously with
the selected model."""
from google.cloud import speech
client = speech.SpeechClient()

with open(speech_file, 'rb') as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()

audio = speech.types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

config = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=16000,
    language_code='en-US',
    model=model)

response = client.recognize(config, audio)

for i, result in enumerate(response.results):
    alternative = result.alternatives[0]
    print('-' * 20)
    print('First alternative of result {}'.format(i))
    print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link ([Google Video Transcribing](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/video-model#speech-select-model-python)) which you have shared in the question says that

> **Extract the audio data**
>   You can use any file conversion tool that handles audio and video files, such as FFmpeg.
>   Use the code snippet below to convert a video file to an audio file using ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i video-input-file audio-output-file
```

So it is definite that you can not directly put **mp4** filein *atleast* a Google api

Also, as the link itself suggests that you have to process the audio synchronously with the video (if you want to display the audio as subtitles/captions).

If you want to know more about how  to synchronously handle these thing. that would be a whole different question with probably many sub-questions in it.